# Failing to inflate layout : Failed to resolve attribute at index

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-toolbar

I'm getting an error when running my app in the emulator: it narrowed it down to the Toolbar layout I'm using, but I can't put my finger on the exact reason.. something about the style I'm using?

This is the output when running the app:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x1c/d=0xff212121 a=2 r=0x7f0c0049}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)                                                                                     
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)                                                                                     
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                                     
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                                                                     
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)                                                                                     
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                     
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)                                                                                     
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)                                                                                  
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x1c/d=0xff212121 a=2 r=0x7f0c0049}                                                                                     
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)                                                                                     
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)                                                                                     
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)                                                                                     
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)                                                                                     
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)                                                                                     
    at com.fontaine.nick.touchevents.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)                                                                                     
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)                                                                                     
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)                                                                                     
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)                                                                                     
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)                                                                                      
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)                                                                                      
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)                                                                                      
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                                      
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                                                                      
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)                                                                                      
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                      
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)                                                                                      
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)                                                                                   
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x1c/d=0xff212121 a=2 r=0x7f0c0049}                                                                                     
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:705)                                                                                     
    at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6890)                                                                                     
    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7071)                                                                                     
    at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1911)                                                                                     
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(AppBarLayout.java:558)                                                                                     
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.generateLayoutParams(AppBarLayout.java:283)                                                                                     
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.generateLayoutParams(AppBarLayout.java:97)                                                                                     
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)                                                                                     
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)                                                                                     
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)                                                                                     
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)                                                                                     
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)                                                                                     
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)                                                                                      
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)                                                                                      
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)                                                                                      
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)                                                                                      
    at com.fontaine.nick.touchevents.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)                                                                                      
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)                                                                                      
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)                                                                                      
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)                                                                                      
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)                                                                                      
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)                                                                                      
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)                                                                                      
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                                      
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                                                                      
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)                                                                                      
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                      
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)                                                                                      
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

my hoofdscherm.xml (main layout that gets inflated):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinaterlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/aandelenlijst"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:onClick="showInputDialog"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="end|bottom" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

my styles.xml:

```
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

the build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fontaine.nick.touchevents"

        minSdkVersion 21 //stond intiaal op 15, mss rollbacken indien problemen
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'

    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.brnunes:swipeablerecyclerview:1.0.2' //voor de cardviews te swipen
}
```

MainActivity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
//de arraylist van strings waarin we de aandelen gaan opslaan die de gebruiker gekozen heeft
ArrayList<String> Aandelenlijst = new ArrayList<String>();

//de arraylist van Stock-objecten waarin de return van de yahoo finance-"get" zal zitten
ArrayList<Stock> mDataSet = new ArrayList<Stock>();

//de Adapter die de bepaalde elementen van de view zal binden aan de desbetreffende properties van de class
StockAdapter adapterke = new StockAdapter(mDataSet);

//handle creëren voor de swiperefreshlayout
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

//handle creëren voor de coordinaterlayout
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

RecyclerView recyclerView;

//connectie makne met DB
StockQuotesDB db = new StockQuotesDB(this);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hoofdscherm);

    //recyclerview stuff goedzetten
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.aandelenlijst);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterke);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    //apptoolbar goedzetten

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Could you add the code, that inflates your layout? Either an `Activity` or a `Fragment`. You're not even using your own theme.

Comment: Added the code for the activity. I've been trying to work around the theme, to make sure the theme isn't the issue